# Google Charts in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, pygooglechart

I am trying to implement google charts on our MVC application. I have made it work so far using stati data so just to see how it would look like on the interface. However, I have created my controller already to retrieve and pass the correct data to my chart. My problem is that my controller does not get triggered from the JS? I put a breakpoint on my controller to check.No errors on the console either...

My **DashboardController**:

```
    public JsonResult GetUploadTypesPerAccount()
            {
                var accountUploadTypes =  _evidenceRepository.GetForAccountPaged();
                return Json(accountUploadTypes , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
```

I created separate **dashboard.js**:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //use ajax
            $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetUploadTypesPerAccount", "Dashboard")',
                    data: {},
                    success: function (chartsDataFinal) {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                        var options = {
                            title: 'Stakeholders',
                            pieHole: 0.4,
                            width: 400,
                            height: 400,
                        };

                        data.addColumn('string', 'UploadType');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'UploadTypeCount');

                        for (var i = 0; i < chartsDataFinal.length; i++) {
                            data.addRow([chartsDataFinal[i].UploadType, chartsDataFinal[i].UploadTypeCount]);
                        }

                       var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart2'));
                        chart.draw(data,options);
                    }
                });
            })
    });
```

Comment: Remove either `$(document).ready(function () {` or `$(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by declaring the Url.Action in the cshtml and then using the global variable in the JS.

cshtml:

```
var uploadTypePath = "@Url.Action("GetUploadTypesPerAccount", "DashboardSummary")";
```

JS:

```
url: uploadTypePath,
```